# Bluetooth LE characteristic from Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read Bluetooth LE characteristic from Xamarin Android Application.

```
m_characteristicReady = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
m_characteristicChanged = new SemaphoreSlim(1);



 public async Task<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> GetCharecteristic(int timeout,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
        {
            EnableCharacteristicNotification(characteristic);
            //Once notifications are enabled for a characteristic, 
            //an onCharacteristicChanged() callback is triggered if the characteristic changes on the remote device:
            m_characteristicChanged.Wait();

            //We serialize all requests and timeout only on requests themself cand not their predesesors
            m_characteristicReady.Wait();
           //todo check result ???
            m_gatt.ReadCharacteristic(characteristic);
            if (await m_characteristicReady.WaitAsync(timeout) == true || 
                await m_characteristicChanged.WaitAsync(timeout) == true)
            {
                m_characteristicChanged.Release();
                m_characteristicReady.Release();
                return m_characteristic;
            }
            return null;
        }

    public override void OnCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, [Android.Runtime.GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status)
    {
        m_characteristic = characteristic;
        m_characteristicReady.Release();
    }

    public override void OnCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
    {
        m_characteristic = characteristic;
        m_characteristicChanged.Release();
    }
```

My question is inside my `public async Task<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> GetCharecteristic(int timeout,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)`
 function

1) `is there a possiblity of a deadlock?`

2) `Is there a way for me to check if the attribute is (notifiable) before enabling notification`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a possiblity of a deadlock?

If both `m_gatt.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);` and `m_gatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);`  methods are invoked asynchronously, it may lead a deadlock. Because you may change `m_characteristic` at the same time by using two `SemaphoreSlim`. Use one `SemaphoreSlim` can solve the deadlock as the following code:

```
    public async Task<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> GetCharecteristic(int timeout, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
    {
        EnableCharacteristicNotification(characteristic);            
        m_gatt.ReadCharacteristic(characteristic);                 
        return m_characteristic;
    }

    public override void OnCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, [Android.Runtime.GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status)
    {
        m_SemaphoreSlim.Wait();
        m_characteristic = characteristic;
        m_SemaphoreSlim.Release();
    }

    public override void OnCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
    {
        m_SemaphoreSlim.Wait();
        m_characteristic = characteristic;
        m_SemaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
```

> Is there a way for me to check if the attribute is (notifiable) before enabling notification

You can use the return value of  `setCharacteristicNotification` as following code to check if the attribute is (notifiable):

```
       boolean isEnableNotification = mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
       if (isEnableNotification)
       {
       //.....
       }
```

But before you call setCharacteristicNotification there is no method to check if the attribute is (notifiable).